# how can i fetch all the tokens from ethereum network to my wallet ?using web3js(nodejs) or web3j(java)?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs, web3j, java

I'm trying to fetch all the available tokens from ethereum network into my android wallet but could not able to find an suitable solution other than web scrapping

Comment: erc20 Tokens? ethereum mainnet? why are you doing that and how (cause there are maybe more than ten of thousands created Tokens)?

Comment: I'm trying to built a dynamic ethereum wallet which consists of multiple tokens for transfer

Answer (score 0):

You could look into a service which does this for you, for example [Cindercloud](https://docs.cinder.cloud/).

Disclaimer: I'm the owner of Cindercloud. There are other services that do this out there, and this is just an example of a service that offers this.